# Снова об однокоренных словах

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

"Голод" и "голый" - однокоренные слова или нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То, что слова не являются однокоренными, подтверждается и этимологией. Полагают, что слово **ГОЛЫЙ** происходит от праслав. *golъ > голъ (голый) значило «лишенный волос» (ср. укр. голити «брить»), затем — «лишенный покрова» (ср. др.- рус. голина «голая земля» (XII в.); укр. голиця «чистое, без деревьев поле»; гiлка «голый прут, ветвь», в нем о > t в закрытом слоге; польск. golka «безостая пшеница»), далее — «не прикрытый одеждой». От прил. **голъ** с пом. темы -ь образовано сущ. **голь** «беднота», «местность, 
лишенная растительности». См. голень, голова.

Слово **ГОЛОД** по корню праслав. Звуков, оформление вост.-слав., с характерным полногласным сочетанием -оло- из -ol- в *goldъ «голод» (ср. ст.-сл. гладъ «голод»). Сущ.* goldъ>, полагают, чередов. гласн. о//е(ь) и согласн. g [г]//ж связано с глаг. жьлдЬти «жаждать, страстно желать», отмечаемым в др.-рус. и ст.-сл. языках (ср. желать).

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что не однокоренные. Я выделил бы корни -голод- и -гол- соответственно.